# Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.1 set selected date +60 days or +2 month

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can I select data from Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.1 by adding 60 days or 2 month to the actual date?

I call datepicker like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        })
    })
```

[This is link to Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.1](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id6

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @DaniP i have been try datepicker form jquery like this $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", "+3"); but still doesn't work